# Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1 during wordcount

Tags: hadoop

When I am executing the wordcount program in hadoop-mapreduce-examples using below command

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.8.5.jar wordcount /wordcount/input/test_input.txt /wordcount/output
```

[image: a]

It is throwing me following exception

```
Exception from container-launch.
Countainer id: countainer_1540539176003_003_01_000002
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode 1;
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Sgell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)     
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Sgell.run(Shell.java:869)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.javaL1170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExcutor.java:235)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:83)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurreunt.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurreunt.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
```

[image: b]

[image: c]

How to fix it?

Sorry I'm new here.

Does it mean there is some memory problems?

Comment: Please paste your actual code / errors in your post, and not inside images.

Comment: add code instead of external link or images. you are beginners on hadoop. i suggest you should used hortonworks for hadoop

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by getting the correct logs.

Look at the `url to track the job` for the address to the YARN UI.

If that address is not available, you can copy the full app id to the logs command

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_1540...
```

From there, you can search for a stacktrace generated by the code.

---

If you've just setup Hadoop, I would guess that `hdfs dfs -ls /wordcount_input/` throws some error about not existing or about permission denied

Comment: `hdfs dfs -ls /wordcount/input/`

Comment: Found 1 items
 -rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu supergroup 38 2018-10-26 15:15 /wordcount/input/test_input

Comment: `yarn application -list -appStates ALL`                                                              
There is application_1540539176003_002                                                     
`yarn logs -applicationId application_1540539176003_002`                              
 /tmp/logs/ubuntu/logs/application_1540539176003_002 not exist.                 
   Log aggregation has not completed or is not enabled.

Comment: Did you go to the YARN UI, as I mentioned? Otherwise, you can try enabling log aggregation, or wait for it to complete if it already is https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/ref-375ff479-e530-46d8-9f96-8b52dadb5183.1.html

Comment: Sorry,I forget to tell you the url is not working,so I just  try to use yarn log. And I complete the setting of  yarn-site. The result  : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server Vm warning : INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000edf00000,104861696,0)failed;error-'Cannot allocate memory' (error=12)

Comment: Is this means memory is not enough?And thank you,I really learn a lot.

Comment: Looks like it, though I've not seen that specific error before